# Get the password to autosave in RealVNC viewer without creating shortcuts or using the address book

Tags: vnc, realvnc

Is it possible to get passwords to autosave in RealVNC viewer without creating shortcuts or using the address book?

Right now I use the [address book](http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2006-August/055832.html):

> - Connect to the remote computer with IP address and password.
> - Once connected, press function key F8 and click "Options"
> - Click "Load / Save"
> - Click "Save As"
> - Choose a name which suits you and click "Save"
> - At the VNC Viewer : Warning about storing the password, click "Yes".

[image]

But I would prefer to use the main window, i.e.:

[image]

to connect.

Comment: where does one download this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to get passwords to autosave in RealVNC viewer without creating shortcuts or using the address book.